# C# : Update Items of SharePoint Library CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I want to modify the value of a Library `item` in SharePoint site.

This is my code:

```
try
{
    List list = myWeb.Lists.GetByTitle(comboBox1.Text);
    CamlQuery caml = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
    ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(caml);
    CTX.Load(items);
    CTX.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (ListItem item in items)
    {           
        item["SEM_x0020_Modif_x0020_in_x0020_the_x0020_server"] = s;
        item.Update(); 
    }

    CTX.ExecuteQuery();
    AutoClosingMessageBox.Show("Done", "SharePoint", 20000);
}
catch
{
    AutoClosingMessageBox.Show(" Error ", "Error", 10000);
}
```

Sometimes this code works well and sometimes this code doesn't update the `items`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Move the ctx.executequery inside for loop and check

Comment: ok, i will try also to add                                       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

Comment: i test it and still not working correctly